# Photoresistors detection

Tags: detection, photoresistor, light-sensor

If I have a 2cm*2cm square and drill a really small hole in the middle thats    barely visible for the human eye, and I place a photoresistor below , will the photoresistor be able to detect any light that comes from the hole?

Comment: If this is your chessboard problem again then you're unlikely to succeed with normal, variable room lighting. You would also be mutiplexing analog sensors rather than simple switches. Tell us again what's wrong with magnets in the pieces and reed switches under the board?

Answer (score 1):

It might work. Let's think of the LDR (light dependent resistor) as a long thin resistor with, for example, a resistance when dark of 1 MΩ/mm. Let's say the resistor path is 10 mm long. Then its resistance will be 10 MΩ.

[image]

*Image from Wikipedia Commons.*

Note from the image that the light areas are conductive and the dark area is the photo-sensitive area. If we could get a tiny portion of the brown track to go close to zero ohms then, theoretically, the device should present a low resistance between the terminals.

Now if you shine a spot of light on 0.5 mm of the resistor and it's resistance dropped by a factor of 1000. In our model above that section would provide a 1 kΩ bridge between the terminals.

This sounds promising but we might find that concentrating the current in a small bridge causes local heating and may damage the device at that spot.

You should try it out and report your results. Note that you may have to focus the light to hit the dark trace. If all the light hits only one conductor or the other there will be no reduction in resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of a pin hole camera: -

[image]

FYI "r" is radius of the pin hole and lambda is the optimum wavelength of the light.

So you can get light thru a pin hole and this will activate the LDR. If you make the distance a few mm behind the pin hole it should get enough light so that the LDR resistance drops noticably.

Comment: I was thinking that too, Andy, but reckoned that most of the light would hit the metallic area and be wasted. It would be fine if the light was really intense.